# MySQL INNER JOIN Alias

Tags: mysql, select

Does anyone know how I can do an inner joins and alias values within so they won't overwrite each other? It might look more clear if you see my code:

```
    SELECT  home, away, g.network, g.date_start 
    FROM    game g
    INNER JOIN team t ON (
        (t.importid = g.home) as home
        OR
        (t.importid = g.away) as away
    )
    ORDER BY date_start DESC 
    LIMIT 7
```

**SOLVED** (After the help below here is my final query)

```
    SELECT 
        home.market AS home_market, 
        away.market AS away_market, 
        g.network, 
        g.date_start

    FROM game AS g
    INNER JOIN team AS home ON (
        home.importid = g.home
    )
    INNER JOIN team AS away ON (
        away.importid = g.away
    )

    ORDER BY g.date_start DESC 
    LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You'll need to join twice:

```
SELECT home.*, away.*, g.network, g.date_start 
FROM game AS g
INNER JOIN team AS home
  ON home.importid = g.home
INNER JOIN team AS away
  ON away.importid = g.away
ORDER BY g.date_start DESC 
LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a seperate column to indicate the join condition

```
SELECT  t.importid, 
        case 
            when t.importid = g.home 
            then 'home' 
            else 'away' 
        end as join_condition, 
        g.network, 
        g.date_start 
FROM    game g
INNER JOIN team t ON (t.importid = g.home OR t.importid = g.away)
ORDER BY date_start DESC 
LIMIT 7
```

Comment: Hey, that is cool -- but Im trying to place both 'home' and 'away' in the same row. I know my question didnt make too much sense. :) This does work if I want a separate home/row record though.