# Multiple inner join when tables have column with same name

Tags: mysql, inner-join, multiple-instances

I have:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
    INNER JOIN cat1 ON products.maincategory=cat1.rid
    INNER JOIN cat2 ON products.cat2=cat2.rid
```

It displays all info fine, but if I `echo $row_rsProducts['category']` I have no way of telling whether the category is from table `cat1` or table `cat2`. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: now your image and query makes no sense nothing matches :) ... but regarding your echo... you should when do `select` give alias.. e.g. select p.id as product_id, etc... then do echo using the alias, i.e. product_id

Comment: Your code would be easier to read with formatting. Check the button with "{}" on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL INNER JOIN Alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724324/mysql-inner-join-alias)

Answer (score 1):

You need to give alias to items that are coming from `cat1` and `cat2` :

```
SELECT products.*,
       manufacturer.*,
       cat1.rid as c1rid,
       cat1.category as c1category,
       ifnull(cat2.rid,'') as c2rid,
       ifnull(cat2.category,'') as c2category
FROM products 
INNER JOIN manufacturer ON products.manufacturer=manufacturer.rid
INNER JOIN cat1 ON products.maincategory=cat1.rid
LEFT OUTER JOIN cat2 ON products.cat2=cat2.rid
```

and than use them like this : `echo $row_rsProducts['c1category']`

Comment: Thank you Fabien that did it.

Comment: only problem I just realized is that if cat2 is NULL or empty it wont show the record. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You need to change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and use the `IFNULL` function to display emply value instead of null in the `SELECT`statement. Check again my answer.

Answer (score 0):

by not using SELECT * but actually naming the columns and giving an alias to each of the same named columns or referencing them by table and column name